# How to reference a parent prop value in a vue-i18n translation string?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I am trying to make a vuetify text field reusable and would like to pass some prop data from a parent component into the validation translation strings as a variable. This prop is a max. character value for validation.

Is it possible to insert a prop or data value into a translation string ? Something like ...

```
props: { 
  maxLength:  { type: Number, default: 20 },
}

i18n: {messages: {
          en: { name_length: "Max. {this.maxLength} characters" },...

}
```

I've tried:

```
"Max." + String(this.maxLength) + characters", but it comes out as undefined.
```

Here's the complete code for reference:

```
<template>
             <v-text-field  

                    v-model="text"      :prepend-icon="iconfront"
                    :rules="nameRules"  :name="name" 
                    :label="label"      :type="type">  

             </v-text-field>

    </template>

    <script>

         export default {

                props: {
                    value: {type: String},
                    iconfront:  { type: String },
                    name:       { type: String },
                    label:      { type: String },
                    type:       { type: String, default: 'text' },
                    minLength:  { type: Number, default: 1 },
                    maxLength:  { type: Number, default: 20 },
                },
                computed: {
                    text: { get() { return this.value },     
                            set(val) { this.$emit('input', val) }
                    }
                },
                data () {
                    return {
                        nameRules: [

                        (v) => !!v || this.$i18n.t("name_rule"),
                        (v) => v && v.length <= this.maxLength || this.$i18n.t("name_length")

                        ]
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    onInput(input){
                         this.$emit('textFieldInput', input)
                    }
                },
                i18n: {
                    messages: {
                        en: {   
                                name_rule: "required field",
                                **name_length: "Max. {this.maxLength} characters",**
                                confirmation_rule: "passwords must match",
                                email_rule: "email must be valid",
                                password_length: "Length must be" + String(this.minLength)+ "-" + String(this.minLength) + "characters",
                        },
                        de: {  
                                name_rule: "Pflichtfeld",
                                name_length: "Max. 20 Zeichen",
                                confirmation_rule: "Passwörter müssen übereinstimmen",
                                email_rule: "Email muss gültig sein",
                                password_length: "Länge: 6-20 Zeichen",
                        },
                        fr: {   
                                name_rule: "champs requis",
                                name_length: "20 caractères maximum",
                                confirmation_rule: "les mots de passe doivent correspondre",
                                email_rule: "email doit être valide",
                                password_length: "longueur requise: 6 à 20 caractères",

                        },
            }
                },     //end of translations
         }


    </script>
```

Comment: Try this way: `en: { name_length: \`Max. ${this.maxLength} characters\` }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this still comes out as undefined

Comment: No problem. I'm just starting to learn Vue and this was what I saw to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 2):

OK, found the answer after a bit of digging:

```
props: { 
  maxLength:  { type: Number, default: 20 },
}

i18n: {messages: {
          en: { name_length: "Max. {max} characters" },...

}
```

Then in the template, you can pass the prop into the translation:

```
 $t("name_length", {max: this.maxLength})
```